# substring issue/question

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, substring

So I have this simple PHP loop that is generating html table data with UPC code numbers (I have 129 total) and the UPC barcode images next to them.

The barcode images vs the upc numbers in the SQL is different by the first and last character. So if I have in SQL 123456789, the jpg barcode is listed as 012345678.jpg. So I have to do some substring work where I add a zero character at the beginning and remove the last one.

All the images appears except for the very last one, and I can't figure out why this is and why the substring doesn't seem right either.

I have the substring working like this in order to remove the last character only:

```
$upcNum = $r[upcNumber];        
$imageName = substr($upcNum, 0, -2);
```

I thought it was supposed to be -1, not -2 to just to remove the last character... by using the above substr method, this is what I get...

$upcNum = "123456789"
substr($upcNum, 0, -2); //12345678

anyhow here's my for loop code, hopefully you can help me shed some light on this annoying issue...thanks!

```
$spiceType[0] = "Chiles";
$spiceType[1] = "Teas";
$spiceType[2] = "Botanicals";
$spiceType[3] = "Spices";
$spiceType[4] = "Herbs";

$counter = 1;       
for($i=0; $i<count($spiceType); $i++){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `spices` WHERE `type`='$spiceType[$i]' ORDER BY ID")or die(mysql_error());
    $spiceCat = $spiceType[$i];
    echo '<tr>
            <td></td><td>'.$spiceCat.'</td>
          <tr>';


    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $pname = $r[productName];
        $qty = $r[qty];
        $price = $r[price];
        $upcNum = $r[upcNumber];
        $imageName = substr($upcNum, 0, -2);
        $imageName = "0".$imageName.".jpg";
        echo'
            <tr>
                <td width="10">'.$counter.'</td>
                <td width="200">'.$pname.'</td>
                <td width="20"><p align="right">'.$qty.'</p></td>
                <td width="50">'.$price.'</td>
                <td width="200"><p align="center">'.$upcNum.'</p></td>
                <td><img src="upcjpeg/'.$imageName.'" height="30%" width="41%"></td>
            <tr>';
        $counter++;

    }
}
```

Comment: `substr($str, 0, -1)` will remove the last character of a string. I'd double-check the url that gets printed for the last image and make sure that an image with that name exists.

Comment: It does exist, and I know it will appear too. Because when I switch the sbustr from -2 to -1, then all 128 upc's will not appear, except for that last one...

Comment: `substr($str, 0, -2)` is removing 2 characters. If that works for all of your images except one then your data must have another trailing character like a space.

Comment: at takteek, yes you were right...but I thought I tried this approach by using the trim() method, now I just figured out that there's a carriage return in the string. How do I trim a carriage return?

Comment: why don't you fix the value in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to chop just one character then it should be -1. Check again those strings.

If only the last image doesn't appear then it's either missing or has a different name.

Comment: super annoying...I know it's supposed to be -1, but -2 is only taking off 1 character at the end.

Comment: no it isn't. trust the php core and make logical conlusions from that. for the last one you have to chop off 2 characters. Either there is an extra character there in the imagename column or the image name has one character less.

Comment: everyone here is absolutely right...i didn't bother checking SQL and the strings all have carriage returns. Now to get ride of the returns.